# Add Tab Pages equal to number of Rows

Tags: vb.net

My Access DataBase has few Rows under single person. Some Person's row count is 1, but another person's row count more than 1.
I want create Tab Pages to insert that person's details.

When Creating Tab Pages,

1. Tab Pages count must be equal to Row Count. (If that person has 04 rows - 04 tab pages must be created.
2. Separate MS-Access DB row data (Column) put in to that tab Pages

If click 1st Tab Page :  -----> 1st Rows of that Person Details (Field Data / Column) should be there with `TextBox`es or `Label`s.

If Click 4th Tab Page : ------> 4th Row of that Person Details (Field Data / Column) should be there with `TextBox`es or `Label`s.

I already created tab Pages according to row count with this code

```
Dim newPage As New TabPage()
Dim RecCount As Integer

While QReaderQ.Read()
    RecCount = RecCount + 1 ' Count How many Rows
End While

TabControl1.TabPages.Clear()

For xXx = RecCount To 1 Step -1 ' to Desending Order ---->3,2,1
    newPage = New TabPage   'create new instance
        If xXx = 1 Then
            newPage.Text = "Repeat - 1"
        Else
            newPage.Text = "Repeat - " & xXx.ToString
        End If
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(newPage)
Next
```

I want put details from Database in to Tab Pages.

Example:

1<sup>st</sup> time repeat data to 1st Tab Page     (repeat Data mean DB Column).
4<sup>th</sup> time repeat data to 4th Tab Page     (repeat Data mean DB Column).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Access, I'm going to assume you're using `OleDb`.  You don't indicate what `QReaderQ` is, but based on the name it sounds like it's an `OleDbDataReader`.

Since (again, according to your posted code) you want to go in descending order, I'd suggest you use the `OleDbDataAdapter` instead - DataReaders are forward-only, so you can't go in reverse order.

I'd also suggest moving your code to create each tab page to its own function, and calling that function from within your For loop.

Putting this all together it might look something like this:

```
Dim TabContent As DataTable
' Pass in your selection string and your connection object
Dim Adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table", con)
Dim newPage As TabPage

' Fill the DataTable TabContent with the result from your select command
Adapter.Fill(TabContent)

TabControl1.TabPages.Clear()

For xXx As Integer = TabContent.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

    ' Pass in the current row - use xXx - 1 since the row collection is 0 based
    newPage = InitializeTabPage(TabContent.Rows(xXx - 1))
    newPage.Text = "Repeat - " + xXx.ToString()
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(newPage)
Next
```

InitializeTabPage is a function that returns a TabPage.  You'll need to create the controls on this page.

```
Public Function InitializeTabPage(ByVal Row As DataRow) As TabPage

    Dim newPage As New TabPage()

    ' Create the control and bind the data from the row to them 

    Return newPage
End Function
```

In the `InitializeTabPage` function, you're taking a DataRow from the table.  You'll need to create the TextBoxes and Labels on each tab page and then bind the appropriate data to them from the row.

For example, if you have a label called `lblName`, and a column in your row `Name`, you could do this:

```
lblName.Text = Row("Name").ToString()
```

Some helpful links:

[OleDbDataAdapter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[A Really Simple Database](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/74114-a-really-simple-database/) - Tutorial on VB.NET and Access